# Tikz-Feynman: massless two point function at two loops

Tags: tikz-feynman

I would like to write on Latex the following Feynman diagrams involving a massless two point function at two loops

[image]

I am using Tikz-Feynman but I am new on it and for the moment I can only write the code for three level diagrams.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier if we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for a basic definition of four node styles that mimic your image.

The output shown below is from `pdflatex`, with `lualatex` the positioning was a bit off.

[image: output of code from pdflatex]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzset{
 Sbase/.style={
   circle,
   draw,
   minimum size=8mm, % increased from 3mm
   /tikz/graphs/as={},
 },
 SA/.style={
  Sbase,
  path picture={
    \draw (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
  },
  label={[yshift=-height("#1")]center:#1}
 },
 SB/.style={
  Sbase,
  path picture={
    \draw (path picture bounding box.west) to[bend right=45] (path picture bounding box.north);
  },
  label={center:#1}
 },
 SC/.style={
  Sbase,
  path picture={
    \draw (path picture bounding box.150) to[bend right=20] (path picture bounding box.30);
  },
  label={center:#1}
 },
 SD/.style={
  Sbase,
  path picture={
    \draw (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north);
  },
  label={[xshift=width("#1")]center:#1}
 },
 SA/.default={},
 SB/.default={},
 SC/.default={},
 SD/.default={},
}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram{
 a[SA=1] -- b[SB=2] -- c[SC=3] -- d[SD=4]
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really thanks Torbjorn, at this point I would like to add momentum line on the internal loop. I was thinking to add them as [momentum] near -- , but this only gives momenta on the two external legs. How can I define them inside the loop? Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: @Andrea.Phys I suggest you ask a new question about that, and do include a complete code example in that. (I know basically nothing about Feynman diagrams, and have absolutely no idea what loop you're talking about.)

Comment: Without talking of loops, I only need to assign a visible number to every line in a diagram. The problem is that I can only assign number on straight lines, while I can't assign any number to the lines inside the circles, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Andrea.Phys I updated, was that something like what you had in mind?

Comment: No, I need to assign a number to every single line in the diagram, where for line I mean a line that starts into a vertex and ends into another one. In this sense I would have to assign to the first circle 3 independet numbers, while for the last one 4 independet ones.

Comment: @Andrea.Phys Add `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`, and try something like `a[SA=1] --["c"pos=0.1, "d"pos=0.9] b[SB=2]`. If that doesn't help, ask a new question. You're asking about something completely different to your original inquiry anyway.